# Transfer File on different server

Tags: php, curl, web, ftp, webserver

I have a plan and there is a must :

1. server 1 = web server, to save source like php and etc
2. server 2 = to save file/document that uploaded by client

client access web server in Server 1 and then upload or download document/image but i want the document or image saved in server 2.
so web source and file/image is separate.

but i don't know what is the ideal concept from transfer file from server 1 to server 2. i try using **FTP and Curl**.
and please consider how to client Download file from server 2.

what is the ideal concept to transfer file like upload or download for scenario above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [PHP FTP.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)
Make sure you have correct permissions to write files on the servers.

Download File using cURL :

```
set_time_limit(0); // unlimited max execution time for big files
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_FILE    => '/path/download/file/server1.img',
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
  CURLOPT_URL     => 'http://server2.com/path/download/file/server2.img',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thanks. i have try something similar. but if using your suggestion I must install FTP Server and Web Server on server 2.

i found a way to upload using CURL, so what do you think if upload and download using CURL not mixed, upload using FTP and Download using Curl or HTTP.

Comment: I'm no Problem install FTP server and Web server on Server2 if it's the Ideal and Good one. But is it the ideal concept ? or any better way but I still don't Know.

Comment: If you got success in upload and download using cURL then its fine.There is no need to setup the FTP server to uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use any CDN hosting providers like Rackspace or any other.Actually I have used Rackspace  were we uploaded files, kept storage separate from the code.They provide you API to upload,delete,retrieve files even you can create directories. They provide you API key and secret key which is used to make API call.While implementing this make common functions which can be used throughout the project to do this operations.

Comment: I'm Prefer not using Third Party from outsider. cause my problem is in the way it transfer file. 
using protocol FTP, HTTP or both.